# From Darjeeling to Pelling

Tags: india

I would like to go from Darjeeling to Pelling by public transport. As I know is i possible by shared jeeps.

Is there a direct jeeps from Darjeeling to Pelling ? How long does it takes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darjeeling is situated in West Bengal State whereas Pelling is in western Sikkim. The total distance is about 73 kms, but due to the hilly terrain it takes about 4.5 hours to reach by car from Darjeeling to Pelling.

Unfortunately there are no direct buses(gov. or private) on this route.

Although, You can get limited shared jeeps from Darjeeling(Chowk bazaar area). The small reserved cab fare is about Rs. 3,800/-. As these jeeps are available on sharing basis it's less likely to follow a proper time-table.

Comment: Thank for your answer. It would be direct jeeps from Darjeeling to Pelling ? And return back - is it possible to get direct shared jeep from Pelling to Darjeeling ?

Comment: Pretty sure that the jeeps would be available both ways, although you can inquire the same at chowk bazar(Darjeeling). But I think there would be some halts in the 4-5hr long journey.